# I am using Visual Composer I received this error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows

I received this Exception while executing Select query:-

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code .The multi-part identifier "sd.MED_ID" could not be bound.

My Code is

```
connection conec = new connection();
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter ;
SqlCommandBuilder sqlCommandBuilder ;
DataSet ds;

private void set_data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conec.conopen();
    //string query="Select S_ID as 'SYMPTOM NO',SD_ID as 'DISK NO',MED_ID as 'MED NAME',SRO,PNR,SYM as '% SYM',DMD from SYM_DETAIL";
    sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select SY_DID,S_ID as 'SYMPTOM NO',SD_ID as 'DISK NO',m.med_name as 'MED NAME',SRO,PNR,SYM as '% SYM',DMD from SYM_DETAIL sd"+
        "inner join MEDICINE m on sd.MED_ID=m.med_Id where sd.S_ID="+txtbxsymid_update.Text+" and sd.SD_ID="+txtbxdiskid_update.Text+"", conec.con);
    ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "SYM_DETAIL");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: The Exception itself states that your SYM_DETAIL table is having problem while binding to your code for MED_ID.

Comment: Can you show us your table structure for SYM_DETAIL?

Comment: Here is table Structure CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SYM_DETAIL] (
    [SY_DID] NUMERIC (18)  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [S_ID]   NUMERIC (18)  NULL,
    [SD_ID]  NUMERIC (18)  NULL,
    [MED_ID] NUMERIC (18)  NULL,
    [SRO]    NUMERIC (18)  NULL,
    [R/A]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [PNR]    NUMERIC (18)  NULL,
    [SYM]    NUMERIC (18)  NULL,
    [NSYM]   NUMERIC (18)  NULL,
    [DMD]    NUMERIC (18)  NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SY_DID] ASC)
);

Comment: Please avoid adding code in the comments. [edit] your question instead to include all the relevant details.

Comment: Sql injection alert: Use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's causing this error:
`from SYM_DETAIL sd"+
        "inner join MEDICINE`

You are missing a space between `sd` and `inner`, so the alias becomes `sdinner`.

Another, more serious problem is that you are concatenating strings to create your SQL statement. This is a security hazard as it's an open door for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
To remove the threat you need to use parameters in your query, so you must use an `SqlCommand` instance.

Also, you should note that `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` all implements the `IDisposable` interface, so you should wrap them in a `using` statement.
I don't know what's the `connection` class in your code but from what I see it contains `SqlConnection` inside. I would not recommend using `SqlConnection` like this since `SqlConnection` should be closed and disposed to return to the connection pool.

Here is how I would suggest writing this code:

```
// a class member
private string connectionString; 

// In your constructor
connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;

private void set_data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    var query = "Select SY_DID, S_ID as 'SYMPTOM NO', SD_ID as 'DISK NO', m.med_name as 'MED NAME', SRO, PNR, SYM as '% SYM', DMD" +
                " from SYM_DETAIL sd" +
                " inner join MEDICINE m on sd.MED_ID=m.med_Id" +
                " where sd.S_ID = @S_ID" +
                " and sd.SD_ID= @SD_ID";
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    {
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@S_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtbxsymid_update.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SD_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtbxdiskid_update.Text;
            using(var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(ds, "SYM_DETAIL");
            }
        }
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```